# Excel array formula returning true for any numerical value not equal to zero

Tags: arrays, excel, boolean, formula

This is the array formula: {=IF(A1:A10,TRUE,FALSE)}, entered into B1:B10.
Cells A1 to A10 contain either '0' or numerical values above or below '0'. B1:B10 results in TRUE for any numerical value not equal to 0 and FALSE for 0.

I understand the Boolean data type being equivalent to 1:TRUE and 0:FALSE, but why do numerical values not equal to 1, resolve to TRUE?

This might have a simple explanation but I haven't been able to find one on the net to satisfy my curiosity.

Cheers.

Comment: Working as intended.  Any non zero value is true, and 0 is false.  In C1 try =Not(A1) and copy down.  or as was actually stated earlier today to me...0 is false, so any other value is true.

Comment: So the reason every other numerical value is TRUE is simply 'because' 0 and only 0 is FALSE? Seems so simple, but it makes sense i guess, being Boolean and all. I was expecting a more complicated reason haha. Cheers.

Comment: I think it may be an excel only thing.  Not sure if you can get away with 42 being true in VBA...though apparently according hitchhikers guide to the galaxy that would be the answer to life the universe and everything.

Comment: So... if Excel tells us 42 is TRUE... and Hitchhikers tells us 42 is the Universe.... and the Universe is everything, does that mean everything is TRUE? :o ... I must contest some of my multiple choice exam results!

Comment: you forgot about life!

Comment: OOOmmmmmggg! ** Mind Overflow**

Comment: Think of it as JavaScript except for string values (which in Excel evaluate to 0 when used in calculation and yield error when used as boolean).